# How to get hammer.js to work with svg files without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, events, svg, touch, hammer.js

I am trying to implement the hammer.js with svg files and without using any jquery.  I'm trying to use the sample code from the hammer.js site {https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started}.  I have the external javascripts called like this.

```
<script src="javascript/hammer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[       
    var element = document.getElementById("testsvg");
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on('doubletap', function(event){
                                 alert("doubletap!");
                                 return false;
                               }
                       );
  //]]>
  </script>
```

My svg looks like the following.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="testsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="585px" height="230" viewBox="0 0 585 230" enable-background="new 0 0 585 230" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="210" width="565" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

Starting out, I'm just trying to get any detection to work.  I do not get any alert when I double tap.  I have also tried to implement this with the hammer.fakemultitouch.js plugin on my desktop.  Neither the desktop or touch environment do anything.
Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrongly?

Thanks,
--christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure `hammer.js` is loading correctly. If it is, then you are most likely executing the javascript before the DOM is loaded. The easiest way to fix this is to place your `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag (near the bottom of your html file). You can also wrap your code in a load event function such as...

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("testsvg");
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on('doubletap', function(event){
        alert("doubletap!");
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I had the script at the start of the body.  I moved it to the end and it works with no problem.